# method successor in class BST cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

Here is the full error code;

.\BST.java:159: error: method successor in class BST cannot be applied to given types;

Node node = successor(node, value);

```
          ^
```

required: Node

found:    Node,int

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Heres a snippet of the code that keeps giving me the error

```
    // predecessor function
    private int predecessor(Node node){
        node = node.getLeft();
        while(node.getRight()!=null){
            node = node.getRight();
    }
        return node.getData();
}

    // delete() method
    public void delete(int value){
        Node node = successor(node, value);
}
```

Comment: Anyone know how to fix it, please?

Comment: The error is telling you that the arguments passed to `successor` don’t match what it is defined to accept. It’s calling `successor(node, value)` when it should be `successor(node)` without `value`.

Comment: Note that `Node node = successor(node);` would also be incorrect, as you can’t use a variable on the right-hand side of its own definition.